# Comparing 7z.exe and 7za.exe

Tags: 7-zip, 7za

I understand that 7za.exe supports a smaller number of compression formats, but I was curious what else may be different between the two, other than just that?

Having some additional information on these would help me understand some of the trade-offs between the two and help ensure I pick the best one to suit my particular needs.

For example, I wasn't sure if one is faster than the other? Assuming that 7za.exe has support for the archive formats I need, what are the substantive differences between the two in terms of such things as specifications, features, and documented performance?

Comment: I found `7z i`, `7za i` and `7zr i` commands useful to compare; `i` lists formats, codecs and hashers supported by each variant.  `7zr` is the slimmest while `7z` is the fattest.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

### 7Z.exe versus 7Za.exe

### Comparison

According to the [Command Line Version User's Guide](https://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/):

> "7za.exe (a = alone) is a *standalone* version of 7-Zip. 7za.exe
>   supports only **7z**, **lzma**, **cab**, **zip**, **gzip**, **bzip2**,
>   **Z** and **tar** formats. ***7za.exe doesn't use external modules***."

In contrast, according to [7z Format](http://www.7-zip.org/7z.html):

> "***7z has open architecture***, so it can support ***any new
>   compression methods***. Now the following methods are integrated to
>   7z: **LZMA**, **LZMA2**, **PPMD**, **BCJ**, **BCJ2**, **BZip2**, and
>   **Deflate**."

***Quick Recap***

- **7Za.exe**: Standalone and less archive formats supported
- **7Z.exe**: Open architecture able to support any new compression methods moving forward

---

### Choosing One

You could choose **7Za.exe** over **7Z.exe** for a more light weight and ***standalone*** utility that doesn't need external modules to function as expected.

You could choose **7Z.exe** over **7Za.exe** if obviously **7Za.exe** doesn't support the newer archive formats for your need or you foresee the need to use newer archive formats than **7Za.exe** will support moving forward since it's ***open architecture***.

Comment: It appears that there is not much more to be said about this. I wish that 7za.exe was included in the 7-zip download.

Comment: To summarize, if you need features such as LZMA2, pick `7z.exe` + `7z.dll` (2 files, 1.27 MB), otherwise pick `7za.exe` (1 file, 637 KB).

Comment: um.. this looks weird to me.. the first point mentions `7za.exe` command line executable and the second part compares it with `7z Format` which is the archive file format.. somehow confused with `7z.exe` executable..