# How do I create a store-only AES256 7zip archive from linux/macOS command line?

Tags: linux, command-line, 7-zip

Creating an encrypted store-only archive seems to be possible through the GUI variants that delegate to 7zip, but I can't figure out the proper command line call.

My failed attempts result in E_INVALIDARG:

```
7za a ~/Desktop/tmp.7z my-big-file -em=AES256 -pMyPass -m0=Copy
```

Comment: In Ubuntu `man 7za` shows the zip file name and the file list as coming _after_ the options.

Comment: Just FYI... here's an answer with a 7z and 7za general comparison.: https://superuser.com/questions/1105516/comparing-7z-exe-and-7za-exe/1105522#1105522. Try it as....`7za a -mhe=on -pMyPass ~/Desktop/tmp.7z my-big-file` and then check to confirm it's 256 bit AES encrypted: https://linux.die.net/man/1/7za

Comment: What did you determine with this @JackWade?

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT `7za a -p -tzip -mem=AES256 -mm=Copy -mx=0 -mmt=12 ~/Desktop/fooBar.zip ~/Desktop/FooFolder`

Answer (score 1):

I've just had to deal with this myself, I didn't find the manual to be perfectly clear on how to use Method Parameters.

Encryption Type is a Method Parameter and needs to be passed as part of an `-m` switch, e.g.: `-mem=AES256`.

Similarly, if you want to do Copy Only (no compression), you need to use `-mx=0`.

```
7za a ~/Desktop/tmp.7z my-big-file -mem=AES256 -mx=0 -pMyPass
```

Comment: And does this command (with the options after the filenames) actually work?

Comment: Works for me just fine on Windows, I imagine it would work in iOS/Unix.

Answer (score 0):

I used `7z a -t7z -m0=Copy -mhe=on -pPassword archive.7z foldername` to get around the `E_INVALIDARG` error.