# 7-Zip -- 7z.exe | 7zG.exe | 7zFM.exe (which one to use?)

Tags: command-line, 7-zip, gui

#### 7-Zip has multiple .exe files, which one do I use?

Every so often I would forget which way round these were, or would try and use one of the .exe's for the wrong purpose, so thought I would get to the bottom of it and then share in case anyone else is curious about the different .exe's.

Comment: "None of them!" j/k but I have come to much prefer [Easy 7zip](http://www.e7z.org/) which has shell (right-click) integration and some UX improvements like (optionally) opening the extracted folder and deleting the source archive, all in one step.

Answer (score 105, accepted):

**`7zFM.exe` is the *main* file you want**

- Technically this is the "File Manager", but I would generally describe this as the "7-zip application"
- Use this .exe if you want to open a .7z (or other) archive, explore it's contents, extract all or some files/folders
- Use `7zFM.exe` when double-clicking a .7z file and Windows asks you to choose a program ("How do you want to open this file?")

**`7z.exe` is the *command-line* version of 7-zip**

- Use this .exe when you want/need to use 7-zip via the command-line
- You could call it a more ‘powerful’ version of 7-zip (you can set quite specific parameters via the command line), however there is no GUI (graphical interface) – double-clicking `7z.exe` won't open anything

**`7zG.exe` can probably be ignored by most users, but is useful in a few (more adv.) situations**

- This is the "GUI module" (which admittedly didn't mean a lot to me at first), but in essence is a second command-line version of 7-zip, but this one will display a GUI (visual) progress/output
- The best way to explain this, and the difference between the main command-line app [7z.exe]…

Imagine you have a 100MB 7-zip archive (one that will take a few seconds to extract), and run the two below commands:

- `7z.exe  x MyArchive.7z -r -o` – Extract the archive, progress/messages will be shown in the console
- `7zG.exe x MyArchive.7z -r -o` – Extract the archive, however there is no output to the console, instead a progress window will appear (with a progress bar, time remaining, etc), as if you had extracted the archive from within the 7zFM.exe application.

Comment: Also see [**7Z.exe versus 7Za.exe**](https://superuser.com/questions/1105516/comparing-7z-exe-and-7za-exe/1105522#1105522) for another related 7-Zip executable file comparison.